# How do I display a queryset based on a category linked to a slug that is requested?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am trying to display querysets linked to a certain category, based on the webpage slug requested. I am in school and trying to learn the Django framework.

Here is the view that I have tried:

```
class ProductCategoryListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'products/product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if Product.category == ProductCategory.title:
            instance = ProductCategory.objects.get(title=instance)
            post = Product.objects.filter(category=instance)
            return post
```

And here are my models:

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True,
                related_name='children', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, null=True, blank=True,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug        = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    price       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)
```

This view loaded the webpage, but did not render any queries.

Comment: Is the slug for a product or a category? can you post the url of your view

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the slug is for a category you can do this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class ProductCategoryListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'products/product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.slug)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
        return products
```

In your `Product` model you can set a `related_name` in the category field, so it's easier to access the products from the category:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductCategory, null=True, blank=True, related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    ...
```

Now you can do this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class ProductCategoryListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'products/product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.slug)
        return category.products.all()
```

Comment: I tried this and now I get the result "local variable 'category' referenced before assignment"

Comment: It’s Category with capital C.